# IIS7 not loading assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, iis-7.5

I am using reflection to pick up a collection of Types to register in a container.

Problem is, after IIS 7.5 app pool recycles or an `IISRESET`, not all the assemblies can be picked up through reflection.

Any way to solve this problem without going through the bin folder and doing assembly load on each DLL?

**Update:**

I am using `AppDomain.Current.GetAssemblies()` to retrieve all the assemblies loaded.

Comment: I think there's a way to reference the assemblies using a section in the configuration file; that might cause assemblies to be loaded. I took a quick peek and couldn't find exactly what I was looking for, but maybe this comment will help jog somebody's memory if such a feature exists.

Comment: The `assemblies` Element for compilation might have some effect http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfyb45k1.aspx by making assemblies known enough to be loaded for reflection. I haven't tried to recreate your situation and use this element though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Don't use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().

Instead, use

```
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()
```

Only quirk is .GetReferencedAssemblies() passes back ICollection (of objects) which you need to cast to Assembly then work with.

Thanks all for your help.

Edit- Credit goes to Dominic Pettifer - "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() Considered Armed and Extremely Dangerous"
http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/44/how-to-get-a-reference-to-all-assemblies-in-the--bin-folder?replyId=357

Indeed.

Tripple Edit. not AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetReferencedAssemblies(). Use the BuildManager class from System.Web.Mvc.

Comment: I think you haven't take a look at those links.. they gave steps and code and also explain how to do it.

Comment: The link is dead. This is why we don't like links on SO

Comment: @devshorts You don't need anything more than BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(). It's a static method on a static class. Not sure what more explanation you need.